# How do I create a new object container on click?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

-- with pure JS ---

I am trying to store the user input into the browser's storage. My code pushes the input into a stringified array. However, once the page is cleared and new input is registered, it only updates the pre-stored data instead of creating new object container for them. How can I store the new input in a new object inside the array instead of overwriting the old ones?

```js
function saveData() {
  var data = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  var formData = [];

  console.log('data', data);

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    formData.push({
      name: data[i].name,
      value: data[i].value,
      type: data[i].type,
      checked: data[i].checked
    })
  }
  localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData));
  let output = localStorage.getItem('formData');
  console.log("formData for localStorage", formData)
  console.log('output', JSON.parse(output));
  document.getElementByTagName('input').reset();
}
```

Comment: localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(formData)); should be outside the for loop

Comment: sure, I moved it

Comment: so the issue is that you want to store a new set of data instead of overwriting the data each time ?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: i think you need to get the localStorage formData, before you add new value.

Comment: @MustafaAnas if you moved `localStorage.setItem(...` out of `for` loop then update the question too, please.

Comment: get the local storage? where to

Answer (score 0):

To store new object either you need to have new `key` value for new object, Or you can create an array of objects in local storage

```
function saveData() {
  let data = document.querySelectorAll("input");
  let formData = [];
  let storageData = [];

  console.log('data', data);

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    formData.push({
      name: data[i].name,
      value: data[i].value,
      type: data[i].type,
      checked: data[i].checked
    })

  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("formData") != null)
    { storageData.push(JSON.Parse( localStorage.getItem('formData')));}
  storageData.push(formData);
  localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(storageData));

  let output = localStorage.getItem('formData');
  console.log("formData for localStorage", formData)
  console.log('output', JSON.parse(output));
  document.getElementByTagName('input').reset();
}
```

Comment: this this taking fromData and putting it in storageData. When new input, it overwrites the formData which later overwrites the storageData.

Comment: 'storageData' is an array so when ever new input will come it ll take old data from localStorage and push new data in storageData and then write back your old +new data in form of array of objects in local storage